# Typescript: clean code remove or decrease if's

Tags: typescript, clean-architecture

Hello I have the following code, where I need to do many checks of calls from the database:

```
 public execute = async ({
    contract_id,
    matricula,
    parent_id,
    patrimony_code,
    product_id,
    serial_number,
    type,
  }: AssignProductDTO): Promise<Either<AppError, ProductInstance>> => {
    //verify type
    if (!(type in ProductTypes)) throw new Error(`${type}, is invalid`);
    //instance checks
    const hasInstance = await this.instanceRepository.bySN(serial_number);
    if (hasInstance) {
      throw new Error(
        `This ${serial_number} product has already been assigned `,
      );
    }
    const parentInstance = parent_id
      ? await this.instanceRepository.byId(parent_id)
      : null;
    if (parentInstance === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Parent Instance dont exist.`);
    }
    //products checks
    const hasProduct = await this.productRepository.byId(product_id);
    if (!hasProduct) throw new Error(`This product dont exist.`);
    //employee checks
    const hasEmployee = await this.employeeRepository.byMatricula(matricula);
    if (!hasEmployee) throw new Error(`This Employee dont exist.`);
    const employeeHasProduct = await this.instanceRepository.hasInstance(
      product_id,
      hasEmployee.id,
    );
    if (employeeHasProduct) {
      throw new Error(
        `The enrollment employee: ${matricula} already has an instance of the product.`,
      );
    }
    //stock checks
    const stock = await this.stockRepository.byContractAndProduct(
      contract_id,
      product_id,
    );
    if (!stock) {
      throw new Error(
        `The product has no stock, or the contract has no supply.`,
      );
    }
    if (stock.quantity <= 1) {
      throw new Error(`The stock of this product is less than or equal to 1`);
    }
  };
```

But this became a very ugly code, but I'm not getting a solution on how to refactor so much if, because they are essential checks for the logic.
I would be very grateful if someone could give me tips on how I can refactor this in a cleaner way.

Comment: This is not really on-topic on Stack Overflow, but is on-topic on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you post there and give a bit more context about what you're trying to do, you will definitely get a good answer.

Comment: ok thank u i go close this post and post on code review

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know about the codereview stackoverflow